# AngularJS: Confusion with $scope and radio button interactions

Tags: angularjs

Why won't the `$scope` change state in this very simple example? When I select each radio button, I would expect to see a console message showing the scope's value had changed. This seems pretty simple, not sure what I'm missing. That said, I'm very new to angular, so please correct me if I'm making assumptions I should not be.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
  <span>Group by:</span>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupby" ng-model="groupby" value="1"/>Option 1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="groupby" ng-model="groupby" value="2"/>Option 2</label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('SampleCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.groupby = 2;

  $scope.$watch($scope.groupby, function () {
    console.log($scope.groupby);
  });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BLSully/WL7as/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the code should read

```
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('SampleCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.groupby = 2;

    $scope.$watch('groupby', function () {
        console.log($scope.groupby);
      });
});
```

or, in the`$watch` expression you can use a function instead of a name

```
$scope.$watch(function () { return $scope.groupby }, function () {
    ...
});
```

using a function has advantages. you can, for example, watch for complex expressions, not just variables.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something stupid ;) Thanks for the answer. Assigning as answer for the extra tip about the ability for the first argument to be a function. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The `$watch` is typically setup on the *name* of the scope property.  So, I'd expect to see something like this instead:

```
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('SampleCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.groupby = 2;

  $scope.$watch('groupby', function () {
    console.log($scope.groupby);
  });
});
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sN6Hz/).

Comment: I knew it was going to be something stupid ;) Thanks for the answer.